# Found nil when adding section, NSFetchedResultsController in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

So, I have a FetchedResultsController in which the user can add rows into a tableView. Depending on what date it is the tableView is supposed to create sections when the user add rows. For example, if you add a row one day the section above it is supposed to display the date you added it, and if you add a row the next day the section should display that date and so on.

The problem is that when I add a row the app crashes and says: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

I also know for a fact that it is the section-related code that causes the error, due to that I could add rows perfectly before I started working with sections.

This is the line that causes the error that i mentioned:

```
 self.foodTableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
```

Here is the code used as the sectionNameKeyPath, where the variable "dater" is a attribute of type "Date" in my core data entity:

```
var formattedDateDue: String {
    get {

        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .ShortStyle
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .NoStyle
        return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(dater!)
    }
}
```

Some other section related code:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.fetchedResultsController.sections?.count ?? 0

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
    switch type {
    case .Insert:
        //ERROR ON THIS LINE
        self.foodTableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    case .Delete:
        self.foodTableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    default:
        return
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {



    if let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections {
        let currentSection = sections[section]
        return currentSection.name


    }

    return nil


}
```

So, to make it even more clear what my problem is; When inserting a new row into my tableView in my fetchedresultscontroller, the app crashes and says that it found nil while unwrapping a optional value. The sections are supposed to be sorted by date.

Also if it wasn't clear enough, this is the code where the sectionNameKeyPath (formattedDateDue) is used:

```
let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: "formattedDateDue", cacheName: "Master")
```

[Breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBZh3.png)

Here are a picture from the breakpoint that was requested:

[1st](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJk2O.png)

There are more variables further down but I can't add more pictures.

Comment: How is foodTableView declared?

Comment: Just as a IBOutlet from the storyboard, it's just a normal UITableView

Comment: pop a break point at the error line, and post a screenshot of the variables just before the crash

Comment: I am quite new to programming, so forgive me if I did wrong, but I updated my question with a screenshot of what I hope was what you wanted.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was asking for. Now expand the "self" variable so that we see the value of self.foodTableView

Comment: I updated my question with a picture showing what you hopefully wanted, however there are more variables further down. So if there is a specific one that you are looking for let me know.

Comment: Interesting, my guess was that `foodTableView` would be `nil`, and it's not

Comment: One interesting thing that i noticed was that if I removed the sectionNameKeyPath, and didn't let the application create sections at all, and then added some things into the tableView, to later on insert the sectionNameKeyPath once again, the application created a section above the things that was added earlier. What I mean is that a section was created over some items that was added before the sectionNameKeyPath was implemented, and when I implement it, a section was created when i restarted the app. Therefore my guess is that it can't insert a section at the moment a new row is inserted.